# Emergency Brakes feel like they are set but are not

Tags: brakes, pontiac, grand-prix, emergency-brakes

When driving my 2006 Pontiac Grand Prix Wide track, it feels as if the emergency brake is on even though it isn't. What is causing this?

Comment: Can you give us more information? Has any work been done to the car lately? Is the gas mileage down? Does the engine rev but the car doesn't go forward? How many miles on the car? Which engine in the car? Which model of the car? *Anything*?

Comment: Do you use your emergency brake when you park?  The caliper could be stuck (you released the brake lever, but the part on the wheel is still sqeezing).

Comment: Check to see if your rear wheels are hot after driving.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my 06 G6. The pins in your calipers are likely seized. Try cleaning or replacing the slide pins. If that doesn't help, it's probably time for calipers.